# Manage Cisco ASA Firepower ASDM

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Cisco recently made available Firepower management via ASDM along with Firesight VM. I am using ASDM to manage and I am unable to see "Create new policy" under Configuration->Asa Firepower configuration->Access policy. The only policy I see is default policy and there is no button to enable it.
[image]
Have control and malware license applied. I tried rebooting firepower module.

Anyone had the same issue?

I am running Asa 5515x version 9.5(1)5, Firepower 6 and ASDM 7.5(2). The latest Java as well.

One thing that may not be relevant: ASDM can't connect to Firepower module when I am connecting via public ip address from outside. I need to connect from inside or connect to vpn and then use inside ip.

Thanks

Comment: This is a comment - You mentioned there is no button to enable the existing policy. Have you tried editing the existing "allow all" policy, using the edit icon? You should also be able to select "Add Rule", to add a new rule.

Comment: I am able to edit and add rules but that doesn't make policy enabled and applied. Actually policy is applied because I see traffic hitting it on the report page. I just don't see the way to update/apply it when I make changes.

Comment: Just curious, why not deploy FireSIGHT, the manager server and manage it from there?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same configuration and software release.
On your screenshot, the Acces control policy has an out of date status. This means you need to deploy ASA FirePower change with ASDM Deploy button.

It will create a task to apply the newest firepower configuration, then wait a few minutes for that task to complete. When Acces Control Policy shows "up to date on device" your access control policy should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Where is Asdm deploy button?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that only one Access Control Policy is allowed on setup I have. I also found deploy button. Feel stupid now:)

Thanks everyone who tried to help!